# Return instance of companion object for daisy chaining

Tags: kotlin

I would like to daisy chain my companion object functions. Example:

```
Company.addUser("bob").deleteUser("steve")

class Company {
   companion object {
      fun addUser(name: String): Company {
         // add user code goes here
         return Company
      }

      fun deleteUser(name: String): Company {
        // add code to delete user
        return Company
      }
   }
}
```

This of course will not compile. How can I return the companion object from the functions so that I can daisy them in a call?

Comment: Oops, sorry. I wrote that out of my head. I corrected it. Replaced Users with Company.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sort of ‘fluent’ interface isn't really needed in Kotlin, as there are several alternatives that don't need changes to the called code.  For example:

```
with(Company) {
    addUser("bob")
    deleteUser("steve")
}
```

and:

```
Company.apply {
    addUser("bob")
    deleteUser("steve")
}
```

And since `apply()` returns the object it was called on, the latter example is also suitable if you want to assign or use the result.

You normally see these patterns with class instances, but they work fine with companion objects too.

They're more flexible than a ‘fluent’ interface, and pretty much as concise.  (You can of course squeeze each of those into one line if needed, separating the statements with a `;`, but it's more readable to have them on separate lines — something that generally applies to ‘fluent’ calls too!)

Answer (score 3):

The default name for the companion object is `Companion`.

[Docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

> The name of the companion object can be omitted, in which case the name `Companion` will be used.

Declare your methods to return that instead:

```
fun main(){
    // compiles
    Company.addUser("bob").deleteUser("steve")
}



class Company {
    companion object {
        fun addUser(name: String): Companion {
            // add user code goes here
            return Companion
        }

        fun deleteUser(name: String): Companion {
            // add code to delete user
            return Companion
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That link to the docs though doesn't really address the issue.

Comment: It wasn't supposed to tell you how to do the chaining. I was just supporting my statement that the default name of the companion object is called `Companion`. @AndroidDev