# Kotlin - conditional chaining of methods

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to chain optionally a method in Kotlin, like for example on a `FuelManager` class, where I would like to have body method as an optional thing, so this would be a request with a body method:

```
val (_, response, data) = manager
      .request(Method.POST, url)
      .timeoutRead(2_000)
      .timeout(1_000)
      .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
      .header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
      .body(payload.toString())
      .responseString()
```

So, here I would like to check if payload exists, then I would add body method, if not I would not add body to a request. Request without body method.

```
val (_, response, data) = manager
          .request(Method.POST, url)
          .timeoutRead(2_000)
          .timeout(1_000)
          .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
          .header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
          .responseString()
```

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68769162/5133585). Consider using `apply` instead of chaining. This way you can put if statements wherever you like. Is each of the chained methods declared in the same type?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with Sweepers comment, that [`apply`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply) may be nicer to use here, e.g.:

```
val (_, response, data) = manager.apply {
          request(Method.POST, url)
          timeoutRead(2_000)
          timeout(1_000)
          header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
          header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
          if (!payload.isNullOrBlank())
             body(payload.toString())
     }.responseString()
```

Inserting an `if`-statement is relatively straight-forward in that case.

If you can't trust that what you have follows fluent API best practice (i.e. returning the actual instance again), you may instead use also something as follows:

```
val (_, response, data) = manager
          .request(Method.POST, url)
          .timeoutRead(2_000)
          .timeout(1_000)
          .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
          .header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
          .let {
            if (!payload.isNullOrBlank()) it.body(payload.toString())
            else it
          }
          .responseString()
```

I.e. putting the `if`-statement inside the scope functions [`let`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#let) or [`run`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#run).

Comment: Drat, you beat me to it by 3 mins :-)  Yes, [`let()`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#let) is the most direct solution here — though, as others have said, these long chains are hard to read and maintain, so there are better approaches.

Answer (score 4):

I think this should do the job

```kotlin
val (_, response, data) = manager
      .request(Method.POST, url)
      .timeoutRead(2_000)
      .timeout(1_000)
      .header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
      .header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
      .apply {
          if(!payload?.toString().isNullOrBlank()) {
            body(payload.toString())
          }
      }
      .responseString()
```

See https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

Answer (score 2):

Like people have said, long chains can be hard to read (especially if you start adding a bunch of logic into them), so it might be better to break it down into some well-named functions instead

```
val (_, response, data) = manager.apply {
          request(Method.POST, url)
          timeoutRead(2_000)
          timeout(1_000)
          header("Content-Type" to "application/json")
          header("X-API-Key" to ctx.conf.get(ConfValues.ApiSecret))
          addBodyIfRequired(payload)
     }.responseString()


private fun WhateverManager.addBodyIfRequired(payload: Payload) =
    apply { if (!payload.isNullOrBlank()) body(payload.toString()) }
```

That way it reads a little clearer, and if you ever need to tweak the logic it can happen in that separate function, and your builder still looks nice and clean. You tend to see this kind of thing in functional programming, where you can have long pipelines of operations, but you create small functions you can chain together in a neat and readable way

Plus with extension functions, you can kinda rewrite how the builder looks - say if you wanted to combine the two timeout calls into one, with named parameters. It's definitely a personal preference thing, but it can really help when there's a lot happening and you want to keep it concise!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [isNullOrBlank()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/is-null-or-blank.html) "Returns true if this nullable char sequence is either null or empty or consists solely of whitespace characters."

Comment: How can I use that for my case where I would not add body method call if payload doesn't exists?

Comment: with the apply { if } from the answer by lambda dude

Answer (score 0):

If you tend to often write code like:

```kotlin
something
    .let { if (condition1) block1(it) else it }
    .let { if (condition2) block2(it) else it }
```

I suggest adding these custom scope extension functions to your arsenal:

```kotlin
inline fun <T> T.letIf(condition: Boolean, block: (T) -> T): T =
    if (condition) this.let(block) else this

inline fun <T> T.runIf(condition: Boolean, block: T.() -> T): T =
    if (condition) this.run(block) else this

inline fun <T> T.alsoIf(condition: Boolean, block: (T) -> Unit): T =
    if (condition) this.also(block) else this

inline fun <T> T.applyIf(condition: Boolean, block: T.() -> Unit): T =
    if (condition) this.apply(block) else this
```

Then you could use them like this:

```kotlin
import my.cool.extensions.letIf

something
    .letIf (condition1) { block1(it) }
    .letIf (condition2) { block2(it) }
```